# Conditional statement in python or pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am querying a hive table using spark.

```
frame = sqlContext.sql("select max(id) from testing.test123")

frame1=frame.map(lambda row: [str(c) for c in row]).collect()

lastval =''.join(frame1[0][0])
```

I am getting a lastval which is what I expect

Now Using this lastval I want to query another table like below

```
abc = sqlcontext.sql("select * from testing.abc123 where id > {}". format(lastval))
```

When the lastval is a integer I am getting No errors. but when the lastval is None then I am getting the script as failed. Because the lastval should be an integer.

How do I specify if the lastvalue is None then take the lastval as `0`

I tried like belwo but still when I do lastval it shows 'None'

```
if lastval is 'None':
 lastval = 0
```

Comment: You are comparing against the string "None". Chances are, you want to compare against the python value `None`. `if lastval is None:`, or possibly actually testing for the empty string `''`.

Comment: @JennerFelton: I believe he actually has a string `'None'`, but the error is closely related: He should instead check: `lastval == 'None'`.

Comment: @Dair I don't use the library but would `if not lastval:` be more Pythonic? Edit: Misread. Would it really return `"None"`?

Comment: @roganjosh: He calls `''.join(frame1[0][0])`, I don't believe `join` returns `None`. But I think it can return a string `'None'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `is` when comparing strings. Instead you should use `==`:

```
if lastval == 'None':
    lastval = 0
```

Or possibly you are saying that `lastval = ''`, in which case you want to check:

```
if not lastval:
    lastval = 0
```